# concourse woker failing with error mounting subsystem 'cpuset' in '/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset': operation not permitted

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, concourse

I am trying to run a concourse server on my debian machine from this repo https://github.com/concourse/concourse-docker/tree/master. I have cloned the repo and generated keys after keys generation i run the docker compose up and containers starting running and then the worker node start failing i inspected the container and found that it is giving this error.
worker_1  | bulk starter: mounting subsystem 'cpuset' in '/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset': operation not permitted
worker_1  | bulk starter: mounting subsystem 'cpuset' in '/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset': operation not permitted

I have inspected the logs and have read few articles. Its cpu mount point issue

Answer (score 0):

I have installed the   apt install cgroup-lite and reboot the system and then resetarted the container and error was gone